# Jest fail to find 'react-dom' in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

Jest fail to run:

```
Cannot find module 'react-dom' from 'node_modules/mobx-react-lite/dist/mobxreactlite.cjs.development.js'
```

Why Jest need `react-dom` in React Native environment? Can't seems to fix it..

my dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.64.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
```

also in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Facing same issue. Please help.